# How do I create a record from both sides of has_many :through association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I add a record from both sides of a has_many :through association?

I have managed to successfully add and remove a Person from a Gym, via a form from within the Gym's page.

But I don't know how to add and remove a Gym from a Person, via a form from within the Person's page.

My models:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :membership
    has_one :gym, through: :membership
end

class Membership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :gym
end

class Gym < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :memberships
    has_many :people, through: :memberships
end
```

My routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :people

  resources :gyms do
    resources :memberships
  end

end
```

My memberships_controller.rb:

```
class MembershipsController < ApplicationController

    def new
      @gym = Gym.find(params[:gym_id])
      @membership = @gym.memberships.new
    end

    def create
      @gym = Gym.find(params[:gym_id])
      @membership = @gym.memberships.new(membership_params)

      if @membership.save
        redirect_to gym_path(@gym)
      else
        render :new
      end
    end

    def destroy
      @gym = Gym.find(params[:gym_id])
      membership = @gym.memberships.find_by(person_id: (params[:id]))
      membership.destroy

      redirect_to @gym
    end

private

    def membership_params
        params.require(:membership).permit(:person_id)
    end

end
```

In the Gym page, I've got a link that opens up this form to select and add a Person to the Gym (actually creates a new record of `person_id` and `gym_id` in the Join `membership` table).

My `memberships/_form.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_with(model: [@gym, membership], local: true) do |form| %>

  <div class = "form-group">
    <%= form.label :Person, class: "form-text" %>
    <%= form.collection_select(:person_id, Person.all, :id, :firstname, {include_blank: true}, class: "form-control") %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit 'Submit Membership', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

In my routes file, if I nest the memberships resource under the people resource and follow the same procedure, eventually I will hit the `memberships#new` action that is already being used by the gyms resource.

I'm stuck and can't figure out a way around this.

Comment: Logically it is not correct to create a belongs_to (gym) object from inside a  has_many(person) object.

Comment: What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: A has_many :through is used for many-to-many relationships, that would be the case if a Person can have many Gyms, and a Gym many Persons. If that’s the case, it should also be has_many in Person. If you indeed want a one-to-many relationship, you don’t really need Membership at all.